# Vue Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError cannot read properties of null (reading 'Address')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

There is an error on clicking on the map is triggered in, time. Arrives in Promise, null. Explain why this is happening? Thank you in advance:

```
onMapClick(e) {
    if (e.latlng) {
    this.post("/api/MapObjectItem/GetObjectInfoByLatLng", {
      Lat: e.latlng.lat,
      Lng: e.latlng.lng
    }).then(result => {
      if (this.jkh.isCreateEvent) {
        this.jkh.selectedMessage = {
          Address: result.Address,
          Lat: result.Lat,
          Lon: result.Lng,
          UsersDataID: this.$auth.user.Id,
          ObjectID: result.Id,
          ToPublish: false
        };
        this.$refs.map.mapObject.setView([result.Lat, result.Lng], 18);
        this.showDetails();
      } else {
        this.obj = result;
        this.changeView();
      }
    });
  }
```

[This Error Promise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOm6A.png)

Comment: Basic debugging: in your .then() callback, put `console.log(result)`.

Comment: What is `this.post`? How are you doing the API request? What library?

Comment: @DecadeMoon axios library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ 'This Error Promise' should not be posted as a link to an image _ You should edit your post by copy / pasting the error message into a code block _ Please take a moment to visit SO Help Center to find out more about the best methods of posting questions >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the javascript is running before the DOM is loaded. ( see Related posts on the right side )
Try running the js inside a function attached to an event listener:

```
    function init() {
      // Run your javascript code here
    }
    
    // Run the 'init' function when the DOM content is loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false)
```